# How to set ObjectId for nested document in golang?

Tags: mongodb, model-view-controller, go

Model:

```
type Vehicle   struct {
    Id          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_vid,omitempty"`
    Brand           string
    Category        string  
    CategorySubject     string
    MakeYear        string
    RegistrationNumber  string
    Model           string
    Price           string
}
func (this *Vehicle)AddToDB(emailId1 string)  {
    sess, db := GetDatabase()
    defer sess.Close()
    c := db.C("user")
    //newId :=Vehicle{}
    /*colQuerier := bson.M{"email": person.Email}
    change := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"profile" : imgName}}
    err = c.Update(colQuerier, change)*/
    colQuerier := bson.M{"email": emailId1}
    change := bson.M{"$push": bson.M{"myvehicle" : &this}}
    err := c.Update(colQuerier, change)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("not inserted") 
    }
}
```

The value of `Id` of Vehicle is empty when it's pushed into `myvehicle` field.

How do I set a value for the nested Vehicle's id ?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by bson id is not set in db. The code tries to update the document which satisfies the query condition. Are you saying myvehicle is not set correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) is auto inserted for document (not sub-document) that does not specify `_id` field. This is to uniquely identify the document.

In your case above, if you are inserting a nested object (sub-document) the `Id` field would not be auto-inserted by MongoDB.

You can however create an ObjectId (unique identifier) for the newly pushed Vehicle document. For example:

```
new_object_id := bson.NewObjectId()
```

See also [NewObjectId](https://godoc.org/launchpad.net/mgo/v2/bson#NewObjectId)